# How to format the csv file with df.to_csv for a multiindex dataframe, python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed dataframe,

```
>>> df
       a1      a2    
       b1  b2  b1  b2
c1 d1  11  21  31  41
   d2  12  22  32  42
c2 d1  13  23  33  43
   d2  14  24  34  44
```

It has 2 levels of header and 2 levels of index. If I directly use the code `df.to_csv('test_file.csv')`, then the format of the file `test_file.csv` is

```
,,a1,a1,a2,a2
,,b1,b2,b1,b2
c1,d1,11,21,31,41
c1,d2,12,22,32,42
c2,d1,13,23,33,43
c2,d2,14,24,34,44
```

However, I would like to change it to

1. remove the duplicates in the 1st level of header
2. remove entire 1st level of index, and make an empty row for each one in the 1st level of index.

The wanted format is:

```
,a1,,a2,
,b1,b2,b1,b2
c1,,,,,
d1,11,21,31,41
d2,12,22,32,42
c2,,,,,
d1,13,23,33,43
d2,14,24,34,44
```

Could you please show me how to do it? Thanks!
Please use the code below.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        ('a1', 'b1'): [11, 12, 13, 14],
        ('a1', 'b2'): [21, 22, 23, 24],
        ('a2', 'b1'): [31, 32, 33, 34],
        ('a2', 'b2'): [41, 42, 43, 44],
    },
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        ('c1', 'd1'),
        ('c1', 'd2'),
        ('c2', 'd1'),
        ('c2', 'd2'),
    ]),
)

print(df)
df.to_csv('my_test_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution. It uses a helper function to remove the duplicated consecutive labels and `groupy`+`apply`+`pandas.concat` to shift the multiindex level as extra empty row:

```
def remove_consecutive(l):
    '''replaces consecutive items in "l" with empty string'''
    from itertools import groupby, chain
    return tuple(chain(*([k]+['']*(len(list(g))-1) for k,g in groupby(l))))

(df.groupby(level=0)
   # below to shift level=0 as new row
   .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([],
                                            index=[g.name],
                                            columns=g.columns),
                               g.droplevel(0)]))
  .droplevel(0)
  # below to remove the duplicate column names
  .T # unfortunately there is no set_index equivalent for columns, so transpose before/after
  .set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(list(map(remove_consecutive, zip(*df.columns)))))
  .T
  # export
  .to_csv('filename.csv')
)
```

output:

```
,a1,,a2,
,b1,b2,b1,b2
c1,,,,
d1,11,21,31,41
d2,12,22,32,42
c1,,,,
d1,13,23,33,43
d2,14,24,34,44
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your useful code. It works! The only mistake is `index=[name]`, it should be `index=[g.name]`. And I also learned from you to use `()` for separating method calls at different lines. :)